# How the TCP ports will be reused after setting ServicePointManager.ReusePort property?

Tags: c#, .net, http, tcp, dotnet-httpclient

I learned from MSDN doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.reuseport?view=netframework-4.6.1) and [this post](http://www.devtips.net/nieuws/nieuwsbericht?nid=2474) that I can *reuse* TCP port for any outgoing connections made with `HttpClient`

> Setting this property value to true causes all outbound TCP connections from HttpWebRequest to use the native socket option SO_REUSE_UNICASTPORT on the socket. This causes the underlying outgoing ports to be shared. This is useful for scenarios where a large number of outgoing connections are made in a short time, and the app risks running out of ports.

I didn't find any other documentation or code example, but I don't understand how the *outgoing ports to be shared*? for instance, I have made below code example

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 8;
        ServicePointManager.ReusePort = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 200)
                              .Select(_ => Client.GetAsync($"https://example.com"))
                              .ToArray();
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static readonly MyHandler Handler = new MyHandler();
    private static readonly HttpClient Client = new HttpClient(Handler);
}

class MyHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    public MyHandler()
    {
        MaxConnectionsPerServer = 8;
        ServicePointManager.ReusePort = true;
    }
}
```

Code has been tested on Windows 10 (.NET 4.6.1, .NET 4.7) and Windows Server 2016 (.NET 4.7, .NET Core 3.0), and the reason I added a customized `HttpClientHandler` because I found in some environment, `HttpClient` does not honor settings in `ServicePointManager`. In the code, I set maximally 8 requests will be sent by `HttpClient` per server, and in total the program concurrently sent 200 requests to the same target server.

All the tests indicated that the process (test.exe) open 8 different ports for processing the total 200 requests, as illustrated by below snapshot.

[image]

I also tried to switch off `ReusePort` property, but the result was identical as above.

So, **what and how exactly ports are shared when I enabled `ReusePort` option?** I was originally thinking, there will be a single port for processing the requests if enabled the option.